# Node.js Twilio HTTP retrieval failure for fax API

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I want to setup receiving fax through twilio API.

this is my index.js file

```js
// const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

// Parse any incoming POST parameters
app.use(bodyParser({ extended: false }));

var parentRef = admin.database().ref();

var updates ={};



 
app.post('/fax/received', (req, res) => {
  // log the URL of the PDF received in the fax
  console.log(req.body.MediaUrl);
  var faxData = req.body

  var faxContent = faxData.MediaUrl
  var faxSID = faxData.sid 
  var faxSender = faxData.from 
  var faxDate = faxData.date_created

  var senderdata = {

    FaxSender:faxSender,
    FaxURL:faxContent,
    FaxID:faxSID,
    
    date:Date.now(),
  };


       updates['/Fax/Recieved/' + faxSID] = senderdata;
        // updates['/Signups/Promoters/' + msgFrom] = senderdata;
       return parentRef.update(updates);

  // Respond with empty 200/OK to Twilio
  res.status(200);
  res.send();
});


http.createServer(app).listen(3000, () => {
   console.log('Express server listening on port 3000');
   });
```

When I tried to run the file and then send a fax to test it
I keep getting this error

> 11200 - HTTP retrieval failure.
>
> 502 Bad Gateway (On server log)

What could I be doing wrong

Comment: Where does the error occurred? Do you have a callstack?

Comment: @James not really sure

Comment: You aren't sure whether you have a callstack? :/ You have an error so you _surely_ have a callstack, post the full error detail.

Comment: @James, I think he has not any stack trace in this case

Comment: Hey @learner101. How did you connect your Twilio phone number to your application here? Also, have you connected up an endpoint that accepts the incoming fax using [`<Receive>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/fax/twiml/receive)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just return some value (`return parentRef.update(updates);`) and not send anything to client. Try to comment `return`